# Why do we call this "Equilibrium Solutions"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

I have a question about the terminology of equilibrium solutions, and my questioning doesn't come from the word "equilibrium" but instead from the word "solution".
For example, consider the following ODE:
$$ y' = y + x $$
If $$y'=0$$ then $$ y = -x$$ but that ain't even a solution to the ODE. Why it is called so?

Comment: I don't think i fully understand your question. Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: Generally an equilibrium solution requires the equation to be autonomous or at least "eventually autonomous". Otherwise, at say time $x=1$ you have the system will not move if $y=-1$, but then immediately thereafter it will start moving. But this can't happen with autonomous equations, at least if you have uniqueness of solution.

Comment: @Dovah-king Could you please clarify: Did you see the term "equilibrium" used for the ODE $y' = y + x$ (which admits no constant solutions), or did you see a claim of the type "a solution of a first-order ODE is an equilibrium if $y' = 0$" and you're trying to reconcile that claim with this particular ODE?

Comment: So we can't talk about "equilibrium solutions" in non-autonomous equations?

Comment: My teacher told me about functions "whose equilibrium solution varies with t" or x. I found that quite odd, i think she may wrong in her terminology.

Comment: Normally "equilibrium solution" means a _constant_ solution. It's possible for a non-autonomous first-order ODE $y' = f(t, y)$ to have equilibria (e.g., $y = k\pi$ for $y' = e^{t} \sin y$), but $y' = y + t$ has no constant solutions. Sounds like a good idea to clarify with your teacher. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That first example is useful, +1.

Comment: @Dovah-king That may have been talking about PDEs, where you can have a function of $t$ and $x$ which does not change with $t$. Then the corresponding function of $x$ is called an equilibrium for the PDE. In an ODE an equilibrium depending on $t$ does not make sense.